# PSTricks: Remove trailing zeros in axis labels

Tags: pstricks, labels

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(3,1)
\psaxes[Dx = 0.5]{->}(3,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is it possible to get `1` and `2` instead of `1.0` and `2.0` (as with `0`) as axis labels?

**Update**

I've also asked this question on [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24334) (and now added [Marco's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153663/15874)).

Comment: If you make a question in LaTeX-Community then you should not repost it in TeX.StackExchange, or vice verse because cross-sites posting is not allowed as far as I know.

Comment: @StiffJokes As long as I make a comment about posting it both places and post an answer, given on one side, on the other, too, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: from a physicians view, it should not be written as 1 and 2

Comment: @Herbert I know. `:)`

Comment: yes, that's true ... :-)

Comment: @CodeMocker Cross-Posts are allowed on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/), the poster should just include a link, so everybody knows. Can save time. Svend did it perfectly, and as I know a cross-post here is fine as well, just not within different StackExchange sites since they topics separate and focused.

Comment: Who removed my second comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution with some internal justification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\makeatletter
\def\@LabelComma#1.#2.#3\@nil{%
  \def\pst@tempA{#1}%
  \ifx\pst@tempA\@empty\the\@zero\else#1\fi% the integer part
  \def\pst@tempA{#2}
  \ifx\pst@tempA\@empty
     \@writeDecimals{}%
  \else%
    \ifnum#2=0\relax\else%
      \@writeDecimals{#2}%
   \fi%
 \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(3,1)
\psaxes[Dx = 0.5]{->}(3,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

A recommended solution with `fp`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}


\begin{document}

\psset{xunit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(3,1)
\psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(3,1)
\multido{\r=.0+.5}{6}{\psxTick(\r){\FPeval\temp{clip(\r)}\temp}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible to modify the labels of the axes directly?

Comment: @cgnieder Good point. What you are asking for is exactly what I would like.

Comment: @cgnieder: I don't know the internal details of PSTricks. Herbert might be able to answer your question. :-)

Comment: What would be the output with the other step value: `\multido{\r=.0+.4}{6}`?

Comment: @g.kov: Then use the more accurate one `\n` instead of `\r`, `\multido{\n=.0+.4}{6}{\psxTick(\n){\FPeval\temp{clip(\n)}\temp}}`.